# Inserting a JFrame with Input and Displaying the Output

Tags: java, jframe, output, user-input, display

I'm new to this place, but I've loved everything I've found on StackOverflow. Right now I'm trying to build on an old program I made for a final project in my java class, but alas I've hit a roadbump.

My program is supposed to request the temperature for the user, then it asks if it is Fahrenheit or Celsius. It then calculates for both Fahrenheit and Celsius, and will tell the user whether or not it is hot, cold, mild, etc.

What I would like to do now, is to be able to run it, and to have it display in a popup window, like it might if this were Visual Basic. Is it possible?

```
package temperaturereader;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.WindowConstants;
import java.util.Scanner;
 /**
 *
 * @author pcstudent
 */

public class TemperatureReader {

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String[] args) { 
    //Declare your Variables
    double input = 0.0;
    double Fahrenheit= 0.0;
    double Celsius= 0.0;
    String ForC;
    String Hot = "It is hot today.";
    String Cold = "It is cold today.";
    String Cool = "It is cool today.";
    String Warm = "It is warm today."; 
    String Freezing = "It is freezing today. Take a jacket.";
    String TooHot = "It is dangerously hot. Stay hydrated.";
    String SunHot = "You are currently standing on the sun.";
    String Oymyakon = "You are in Oymyakon, Russia.";


    //Asking for Temperature
    Scanner one = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter the temperature:");
    input = one.nextDouble();

    //Asking for Fahrenheit or Celsius
    Scanner two = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Is the temperature in Fahrenheit or Celsius?");
    ForC = two.next();


    //Check for Fahrenheit and convert accordingly
    if (ForC.equalsIgnoreCase("Fahrenheit")) {
        Fahrenheit = input;
        Celsius = (Fahrenheit -32)*.5556; 
    } 
    else if (ForC.equalsIgnoreCase("F")) {
        Fahrenheit = input;
        Celsius = (Fahrenheit -32)*.5556;
    }
    //Check for Celsius and convert accordingly
    else if (ForC.equalsIgnoreCase("Celsius")) {
        Celsius = input;
        Fahrenheit = (Celsius*1.8) + 32;
    }
    else if (ForC.equalsIgnoreCase("C")){
        Celsius = input;
        Fahrenheit = (Celsius*1.8) + 32;
    }

    //If there is an error, stop the program.
    else {
        System.out.println("Error.");
            System.exit(0);
    }

    System.out.println(""); 


    //Compare temperatures and display.

    if (Fahrenheit >= 9941) {
        System.out.println("The temperature is currently " + Fahrenheit + " degrees Fahrenheit and " + Celsius + " degrees Celsius.");
        System.out.println("");
        System.out.println(SunHot);
    }

    else if (Fahrenheit >= 105) {
        System.out.println("The temperature is currently " + Fahrenheit + " degrees Fahrenheit and " + Celsius + " degrees Celsius.");
        System.out.println("");
        System.out.println(TooHot);
    }

    else if (Fahrenheit >= 80) {
        System.out.println("The temperature is currently " + Fahrenheit + " degrees Fahrenheit and " + Celsius + " degrees Celcius.");
        System.out.println("");
        System.out.println(Hot);
    }
    else if (Fahrenheit >= 60) {
        System.out.println("The temperature is currently " + Fahrenheit + " degrees Fahrenheit and " + Celsius + " degrees Celsius.");
        System.out.println("");
        System.out.println(Warm);            
    }
    else if (Fahrenheit >= 59) {
        System.out.println("The temperature is currently " + Fahrenheit + " degrees Fahrenheit and " + Celsius + " degrees Celsius.");
        System.out.println("");
        System.out.println(Cool);     
    }
    else if (Fahrenheit >= 40) {
        System.out.println("The temperature is currently " + Fahrenheit + " degrees Fahrenheit and " + Celsius + " degrees Celsius.");
        System.out.println("");
        System.out.println(Cold);    
    }

    else if (Fahrenheit >= 32) {
        System.out.println("The temperature is currently " + Fahrenheit + " degrees Fahrenheit and " + Celsius + " degrees Celsius.");
        System.out.println("");
        System.out.println(Freezing);
    }

    else if (Fahrenheit >= -58) {
        System.out.println("The temperature is currently " + Fahrenheit + " degrees Fahrenheit and " + Celsius + " degrees Celsius.");
        System.out.println("");
        System.out.println(Oymyakon);
    }
    else {
        System.out.println("");
    }

}
```

Comment: what's problem you get?

Comment: Is is possible?  Yes.  There are all kinds of tutorials available on the web.  StackOverflow isn't for "hey, tell me how to do this", it's for showing what you've tried and explaining where you're stuck.  Please see http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask for some guidance.

Comment: To start with, SO is not a tutorial site, so you're going to have to make some kind of effort on your own to start with.  I recommend starting with [Creating a GUI With JFC/Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/) and [How to Make Frames (Main Windows)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/frame.html).  You could also have a look at [Getting started with JavaFX](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/get_started/jfxpub-get_started.htm)

Answer (score 1):

You may start from here (I tried to optimize your code):

```
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JComboBox;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

public class TemperatureReader {
    private double Fahrenheit= 0.0;
    private double Celsius= 0.0;
    private String ForC;
    private final String Hot = "It is hot today.",  Cold = "It is cold today.", Cool = "It is cool today.",Warm = "It is warm today.",
                         Freezing = "It is freezing today. Take a jacket.",TooHot = "It is dangerously hot. Stay hydrated.",
                         SunHot = "You are currently standing on the sun.",Oymyakon = "You are in Oymyakon, Russia.";

 public static void main(String[] args) { 
     TemperatureReader tr = new TemperatureReader();
     // a very simple JFrame , it can be improved but this is just an example 
     JFrame jf = new JFrame("Temperature Reader");
     jf.setSize(700, 400); // you can change this 
     jf.getContentPane().setLayout(new FlowLayout());
     JTextField t = new JTextField("", 12);
     String []types = {"Fahrenheit", "Celsius"};
     t.setHorizontalAlignment(JTextField.LEFT);
     JComboBox<String> type = new JComboBox<String>(types);
     type.setSelectedIndex(0);
     jf.getContentPane().add(t);
     JTextField result = new JTextField("", 60);
     result.setHorizontalAlignment(JTextField.RIGHT);
     JButton btn = new JButton("Calculate");
     jf.getContentPane().add(t);
     jf.getContentPane().add(type);
     jf.getContentPane().add(result);
     jf.getContentPane().add(btn);
     jf.setVisible(true);

     btn.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

         @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
             double input = 0.0;
             // you need to validate it first and check if it's not empty and contains only digits ..etc 
             input = Double.valueOf(t.getText());
             tr.setForC(type.getSelectedItem().toString());

            switch(tr.getForC()){
            case  "Fahrenheit":
                tr.setCelsius((input -32)*.5556);
                tr.setFahrenheit(input);
                break;

            case "Celsius":
                tr.setFahrenheit((input*1.8) + 32);
                tr.setCelsius(input);
                break;
        }

            double f = tr.getFahrenheit();
            double c = tr.getCelsius();
            String display = (f>=9941)? tr.result(f, c, tr.getSunHot()):
                             (f>= 105)? tr.result(f, c, tr.getTooHot()):
                             (f>= 80)?  tr.result(f, c, tr.getHot()):
                             (f>= 60)?  tr.result(f, c, tr.getWarm()):
                             (f>= 59)?  tr.result(f, c, tr.getCool()):
                             (f>= 40)?  tr.result(f, c, tr.getCold()):
                             (f>= 32)?  tr.result(f, c, tr.getFreezing()):
                             (f>= -58)? tr.result(f, c, tr.getOymyakon()): "Error";


               result.setText(display);
        }
    });
   }


    public String result(double f, double c, String s){
        return "The temperature is currently " + f + " degrees Fahrenheit and " + c + " degrees Celsius.\n" + s + "\n";
    }

    public double getFahrenheit() {
        return Fahrenheit;
    }

    public void setFahrenheit(double fahrenheit) {
        Fahrenheit = fahrenheit;
    }

    public double getCelsius() {
        return Celsius;
    }

    public void setCelsius(double celsius) {
        Celsius = celsius;
    }

    public String getForC() {
        return ForC;
    }

    public void setForC(String forC) {
        ForC = forC;
    }

    public String getHot() {
        return Hot;
    }

    public String getCold() {
        return Cold;
    }

    public String getCool() {
        return Cool;
    }

    public String getWarm() {
        return Warm;
    }

    public String getFreezing() {
        return Freezing;
    }

    public String getTooHot() {
        return TooHot;
    }

    public String getSunHot() {
        return SunHot;
    }

    public String getOymyakon() {
        return Oymyakon;
    }

}
```

Answer (score -1):

so you need to create a new window for display the result to user?

create new jFrame class and create a new object of that class and make it visible by `objName.show(true)`

Comment: Okay, but how does the OP make a frame, how does the OP add controls to the frame, how does the OP interact with the controls and manage the events - the question is too broad for SO and your answer is a reflection of how bad it is